# Kotlin / Java - Filter by unknown Type

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin

Is any solution for given situation that
I have List of Objects and I'd like to filter it by given predicate but i don't know type of filter param.

What I do know than filter param can be

1. List of Long
2. String but only "ALL" word
3. null

- When param is List<_Long> i have to return Object with IDs contained in param
- When param is "ALL" or null i have to return all objects

Have anyone idea how can do this ??

Comment: Are you looking for help defining the type of the filter parameter? Or are you stuck with a `Any` and want to know how to deal with it?

Comment: Filter type parametr can be a list, string or null. Im stuck with Any

Answer (score 0):

If you're really stuck with `Any?` you could use this rather unsafe way:

```kotlin
fun getFilteredItems(param: Any?): List<Item> = when(param) {
    "ALL", null -> items
    is List<*> -> items.filter { it.id in param }
    else -> error("Invalid filter parameter '$param'")
}
```

But that doesn't fail if the list contains other things than `Long`, it will just return an empty list in that case.

A better, more type-safe way is to type your parameter with a sealed class:

```kotlin
sealed class Filter {

    object All : Filter()

    data class ById(val ids: List<Long>): Filter()
}

fun getFilteredItems(param: Filter): List<Item> = when(param) {
    Filter.All -> items
    is Filter.ById -> items.filter { it.id in param.ids }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for solution ! But something is wrong because is getting error Invalid filter parameter when i try with Long

Comment: Do you mean with a `List<Long>` or with just one `Long`? Those are not the same things. Also be careful that long literals require a `L` suffix if type inference is not enough. The code in my answer seems to work fine in the playground: https://pl.kotl.in/ouoteCn5L

Comment: Have you considered the proper solution with the sealed class, though?

Comment: Yes, i used lates version of you post :D Not working for LIst<Long> and Long with 'L' and without 'L'

Comment: little weird, it works for you :/

Comment: In solution with sealed Filter, a Filter.ByIds is unresolved reference and param.ids to

Comment: There was a typo, `ById` on one side `ByIds` on the other, make sure they are the same. Also I forgot the `is` in the second `when` condition

Comment: Filter.Id Classifier 'ById' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here and param.ids is still unresolverReference

Comment: Yep I had just edited my comment :) I had forgotten the `is`. Please check the updated answer, it works fine: https://pl.kotl.in/DUyo8Kiq5

Comment: finally no errors in IJ ;) But 
Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.domain.service.Filter'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.domain.service.Filter': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]

Comment: I think it works in console, fun not i endpoint, i try to use "Filter" as  @RequestParam

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245244/discussion-between-mat373-and-joffrey).